# How to run the Install4j Command Line Compiler on macOS?

Tags: install4j

I can build my install4j (Gradle) project on Windows using the command line compiler, but I now need to do the same on macOS (for app notarization). I only see references to the Windows .exe in the [documentation](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/cli/compiler.html). Is there a command line compiler for macOS or should I try the Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line utilities on macOS are located inside the application bundle. In the toolbar of the install4j IDE on macOS there is a "Tools" button that gives you access to two actions:

1. Show the tools directory in the finder
2. Install symbolic links, so you can access them in any terminal window